# Using brackets in PowerShell when sending a request

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I am trying to send a request with following body in ISE:

```
$body = @{
  'roles'=['write'],
  "grantedToIdentities": [{
    "application": {
      "id": "xx-7736-4e25-95ad-3fa95f62b66e",
      "displayName": "Contoso Time Manager App"
    }
  }]
}

$Result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/xx-53D2-xx-A368-A7F3E475F0A0/permissions' -Headers $Headers
write-host $Result
```

However I can see I need to escape the brackets. Any pointers on how to make a request like this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to express an array in PowerShell, you can use the `@()` syntax. In addition, you have to omit the comma after each property and define objects/hashtables using the `@{}` syntax . This is how your body could look like:

```
$body = @{
    roles               = @('write')
    grantedToIdentities = @( @{
            application = @{
                id          = "xx-7736-4e25-95ad-3fa95f62b66e"
                displayName = "Contoso Time Manager App"
            }
        })
}
```

And this is how the corresponding JSON looks like:

```
{
  "roles": [
    "write"
  ],
  "grantedToIdentities": [
    {
      "application": {
        "id": "xx-7736-4e25-95ad-3fa95f62b66e",
        "displayName": "Contoso Time Manager App"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

This will match the expected payload for the [Create permission Graph request](https://learn.microsoft.com/graph/api/site-post-permissions?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http&WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5003203#examples).

**⚠ Note:** You are not adding the `$body` object to the request in your example.

Comment: The "⚠" is a nice touch :)